# Run-time Error 1004 using NetworkDays_Intl

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting a 'run-time error 1004' when ever trying to run the below code. I've tried breaking it out but just can't see what is triggering. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Processing").Cells(i, 14) = (WorksheetFunction.NetworkDays_Intl(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Processing").Cells(i - 1, 2), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Processing").Cells(i, 2), 1, (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Validation").Range(Cells(3, 3), Cells(31, 3)) - 1)) _
                    * (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Validation").Cells(3, 2) - ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Validation").Cells(3, 1)) _
                    + Calc _
                    - WorksheetFunction.Median( _
                                                WorksheetFunction.NetworkDays_Intl(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Processing").Cells(i - 1, 2), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Processing").Cells(i - 1, 2), 1, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Validation").Range(Cells(3, 3), Cells(31, 3))) * ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Processing").Cells(i - 1, 2) Mod 1, _
                         ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Validation").Cells(3, 1), _
                         ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Validation").Cells(3, 2)))
```

Full Code:

```
Sub PendingCustomer()

Dim i, LastRow As Integer
Dim Calc As Integer

    LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Processing").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Processing").Cells(i, 10) = "3") Or (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Processing").Cells(i, 10) = "4") Then
            If (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Processing").Cells(i, 5) = "Pending - Customer") And (UCase(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Processing").Cells(i, 9)) Like "VZB*") And (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Processing").Cells(i, 8) > ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Processing").Cells(i - 1, 8)) Then
                If WorksheetFunction.NetworkDays_Intl(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Processing").Cells(i, 2), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Processing").Cells(i, 2), 1, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Validation").Range("C3:C31")) > 0 Then
                    Calc = WorksheetFunction.Median(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Processing").Cells(i, 2) Mod 1, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Validation").Cells(2, 2), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Validation").Cells(3, 2))
                Else: Calc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Validation").Cells(3, 2)
                End If
                
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Processing").Cells(i, 14) = (WorksheetFunction.NetworkDays_Intl(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Processing").Cells(i - 1, 2), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Processing").Cells(i, 2), 1, (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Validation").Range(Cells(3, 3), Cells(31, 3)) - 1)) _
                    * (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Validation").Cells(3, 2) - ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Validation").Cells(3, 1)) _
                    + Calc _
                    - WorksheetFunction.Median( _
                                                WorksheetFunction.NetworkDays_Intl(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Processing").Cells(i - 1, 2), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Processing").Cells(i - 1, 2), 1, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Validation").Range(Cells(3, 3), Cells(31, 3))) * ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Processing").Cells(i - 1, 2) Mod 1, _
                         ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Validation").Cells(3, 1), _
                         ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Validation").Cells(3, 2)))
                
            End If
        ElseIf (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Processing").Cells(i, 5) = "Pending - Customer") And (UCase(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Processing").Cells(i, 9)) Like "VZB*") And (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Processing").Cells(i, 8) > ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Processing").Cells(i - 1, 8)) Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Processing").Cells(i, 14) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Processing").Cells(i, 2) - ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Processing").Cells(i - 1, 2)
        Else: ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Processing").Cells(i, 14) = ""
        End If
        
    Next
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Processing").Columns(14).NumberFormat = "[mm]:ss"

End Sub
```

Data Set:

[Validation Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxcX6.png)

[Processing Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2WVo.png)

Comment: On the If statements? Because they are And/Or If statements so I am keeping the grouping.

Comment: I cannot see any immediate flaws in your code. I get the use of brackets - it looks cleaner, but I guess that's just personal preference. Maybe provide a screenshot of your dataset? That way, it'd be easier to recreate the issue rather than interpret your code and recreate it.

Comment: Thanks @HavardKleven, I've added the images of the two datasets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue found.

In the NetworkDays_Intl function:

```
.Range(Cells(3, 3), Cells(31, 3))
```

does not work, had to use

```
.Range("C3:C31")
```